# Java expanding circle

Tags: java

I am trying to have an applet draw a circle starting with the size of the beginning radius expanding over and over until it reaches the end size of radius. Just need a push in the right direction this is what i have so far..

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class circleExpandv1 extends JApplet
{
    public void paint( Graphics g )
    {
        super.paint( g ); //instantiate g with paint

        Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.print( "\nEnter beginning radius > " );
        int radiusStart = scan.nextInt();  

        System.out.print( "\nEnter ending radius > " );
        int radiusEnd = scan.nextInt();  

        int centerX0 = 150, centerY0 = 50; // set x y cordinates
        int radius0 = radiusStart;  // set radius                 

        int centerX1 = 150, centerY1 = 50; // set x y cordinates
        int radius1 = radiusEnd;  // set radius

        while ( radiusStart != radiusEnd )
        {
             if ( radius0 < radius1 )
             {
                 g.drawOval( centerX0 - radius0, centerY0 - radius0, radius0 * 2, radius0 * 2 ); //draw oval
             }
        }

        //g.clearOval( centerX0 - radius0, centerY0 - radius0, radius0 * 2, radius0 * 2 ); //clear oval

        }
    }
```

Comment: um.... what's your question?

Comment: It only draw one circle I need the program to draw a circle over and over until it is equal to the radiusEnd

Comment: Two things.  DON'T block the EDT and DON't block the EDT.  Using `Scanner` in a GUI and especially in an applet is ill advised, but doing it inside the `paint` method is just plainly...ask for trouble.  The same thing gose for the `while` loop...Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( radiusStart != radiusEnd )
{
    if ( radius0 < radius1 )
    {
        g.drawOval( centerX0 - radius0, centerY0 - radius0, radius0 * 2, radius0 * 2 ); //draw oval
    }

}
```

This will loop forever (or not at all), since the code inside the loop does not change radiusStart or radiusEnd. Perhaps this gives you the requested "push in the right direction"?

Comment: I added radius0 += 20 after drawOval that draws a bullseye is there anyway to clear the oval after it is drawn

Answer (score 0):

Swing is a single threaded environment, that is, all updates to the UI are expected to occur within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  This also means that any operation that blocks this thread, will prevent the EDT from processing new events, included repaint requests.

`paint` can be called at any time and the expectations are that you will repaint the state of the component.

`paint` is expected to run as fast as possible otherwise it will slow down the repaint process.

You should avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers, instead opting to creating a custom component, extending from something like a `JPanel`, and override it's `paintComponent` method.

Start by taking a look at

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

In your case, I might suggest using a `javax.swing.Timer` to trigger updates at a regular interval until you've accomplished the end result (of drawing a circle).

Remember, animation is an illusion of change of over time...

You are also trying to operate within a graphical environment.  This is an event driven environment and trying to get user input via `Scanner` doesn't make sense, nor will you find it particularly useful when using a `JApplet`, as the user has no means to respond to the request.

Instead, you should be making use of the various UI components you have available to get user input, including, but not limited to, `JTextField`, `JSpinner`, `JFormattedTextField` and `JButton`

Take a look at [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more details.

I would, personally, avoid using `JApplet` at this time, as it brings it own complications and stick to using something like `JFrame` as your primary top level container.